# Last modified using format_interval

Tags: nodes

I would like to show interval time for nodes were last modified. I am using the following code:

```
<?php print "Last Modified" . format_interval($node->changed, $langcode, "short"); ?>
```

I am using `$langcode` as proposed [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7) to display it in Arabic, but it is not working and I am not sure if I am using it the right way because I get this error ***Notice: Undefined variable: langcode in include()***

Whenever I update any content; interval time still set to 0 sec, so what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains two errors:

- You are using a variable which has not been initialized
- You are passing the wrong arguments to [`format_interval()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7)

The required arguments are:

- `$interval`
  It's not a timestamp, but the number of seconds until now. In your case, you should use `time() - $node->changed`.
- `$granularity`
  It's the number of units that are shown; if you pass 2 as value for `$granularity` and the interval is for 1 year, 3 months, and 2 weeks, `format_interval()` will return `"1 year 3 months"`.
- `$langcode`
  It's the language code for the language to use. If you are hard-coding the language to be Arabic, you should use `"ar"`.